# panda dataframe extracting values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called "nums" and am trying to find the value of the column "angle" by specifying the values of other columns like this:

```
nums[(nums['frame']==300)&(nums['tad']==6)]['angl']
```

When I do so, I do not get a singular number and cannot do calculations on them. What am I doing wrong?
[nums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNpkj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in general you should use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) rather than concatenate indexes like that:

```
>>> s = nums.loc[(nums['frame']==300)&(nums['tad']==6), 'angl']
```

Now, to get the float, you may use the [`.item()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.item.html) accessor.

```
>>> s.item()
-0.466331
```